# Multivariate Normal density Calculation for every point in dataset

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, density-estimation

I am assuming a multivariate dataset to be normally distributed. First I calculated mean and var-covariance matrix, then to calculate density at each point in the dataset. I used the below code:

```r
library(mvtnorm)

for (i in 1:nrow(label) {

  # label is name of multivariate dataset with 103 attributes
  f_x = dmvnorm(label[i,], mu, sigma)
        
  print(f_x)

}
```

But `f_x` is `0` on every iteration for this dataset. Can anybody explain why?

label[i,]=  -0.085967 -0.104563 -0.336281 -0.059032 -0.120714 -0.056886  0.080746 -0.076670 -0.073521
[10]  0.116667 -0.039577  0.033594 -0.093181 -0.076071 -0.165034 -0.052967 -0.015580 -0.040092
[19]  0.069600  0.074564 -0.197139  0.090742  0.067599  0.045059  0.038602  0.197904  0.128142
[28]  0.120801  0.129524  0.105941  0.134739  0.101043  0.120411  0.060964  0.011318 -0.004465
[37]  0.113363 -0.039590  0.054318  0.016265 -0.023962  0.139066  0.092707 -0.051793  0.111594
[46]  0.055601  0.088289  0.045012 -0.095693 -0.005392  0.013786 -0.015921 -0.021408 -0.020224
[55]  0.006708 -0.022336  0.000322  0.003766 -0.097727 -0.059341 -0.105995  0.043798 -0.062448
[64]  0.283686 -0.006354 -0.090631 -0.034770 -0.028722 -0.190479 -0.215274 -0.013533  0.188903
[73]  0.065210 -0.051470 -0.035804  0.072192 -0.041506 -0.065696 -0.170535 -0.059859 -0.073217
[82]  0.036459 -0.110320 -0.037079  0.085997 -0.004966  0.043294  0.187720  0.136251  0.103049
[91]  0.109268  0.043283 -0.115915  0.055616 -0.112063 -0.020210 -0.086500 -0.104633 -0.041141
[100]  0.066375 -0.118725 -0.049187  0.036005

mu=   -0.0189516765 -0.0528536176 -0.0595148235 -0.0249159412 -0.0076849706  0.0308212941
[7]  0.0272432647  0.0011987647 -0.0071816471 -0.0021682941 -0.0337130000 -0.0285621765
[13]  0.0026446765 -0.0008043529 -0.0007966765  0.0101645294  0.0298982647  0.0125836176
[19]  0.0122494118  0.0075484412 -0.0399482941 -0.0141849118  0.0040878529 -0.0121186471
[25] -0.0022635294 -0.0153491765 -0.0123652353 -0.0289397647  0.0115252059  0.0016887059
[31] -0.0060491765 -0.0043438824 -0.0127446765  0.0232548824  0.0173281176  0.0233317941
[37] -0.0043015000  0.0015853235 -0.0286051176  0.0265263824 -0.0022183529 -0.0034573824
[43] -0.0248249706 -0.0215291471 -0.0070806471 -0.0146559706 -0.0254031471 -0.0046468529
[49]  0.0332078529  0.0537462647  0.0539925000  0.0376399118  0.0295436176 -0.0297920294
[55]  0.0145206765 -0.0092549412  0.0543320882  0.0634597059 -0.0210486471 -0.0406796765
[61] -0.0304955294 -0.0254195588 -0.0224629118 -0.0017282059  0.0018351176  0.0103927941
[67] -0.0094835882 -0.0171998529 -0.0213354706 -0.0063368235  0.0068913235  0.0341634118
[73] -0.0098097353 -0.0263983235 -0.0271716765 -0.0316894706 -0.0418860294 -0.0090717647
[79] -0.0269180000 -0.0106435882 -0.0264100882 -0.0200908529 -0.0123046471 -0.0111469412
[85]  0.0115104706 -0.0130700294 -0.0223370000 -0.0296195588 -0.0070229706  0.0561700588
[91]  0.0666597941  0.0332724412 -0.0200297353 -0.0007494412 -0.0081482059 -0.0353238235
[97] -0.0066679412 -0.0184767941 -0.0078042059 -0.0086050588 -0.0129123529  0.0162377647
[103]  0.0441830000

sigma=[image]

Comment: Can you fix the code to be exactly what you used? What you have there is not syntactically valid, and `mvtnorm::dmvnorm` doesn't have a `use.names` argument.

Comment: Sorry for the error, I've corrected it. I know there is no physical significance of density value at a given point, but still, I need this to calculate another measure

Comment: I used mvnfast::dmvn for density calculation too, but it threw error-                                                          error: chol(): decomposition failed
Error in dmvn(mu, mu, sigma) : chol(): decomposition failed

Comment: can you provide or show what is mu and sigma, and label? You do not need to iterate with a loop, in theory it can accept a matrix

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but in R you can avoid loops by applying directly a function to all your data.

Comment: Probably, your variables are far too off from the mean, please share an example mu, sigma and label[i,] to verify.

Comment: Updated:- One sample instance, mu, and a small snippet of sigma. I hope it helps

Comment: It would suffice--and be far clearer--to supply a *single* value of $(\mu,\sigma)$ to illustrate the problem.

Comment: one instance and mu are a 103 long vector, sigma is 103*103 matrix of which I have a given a small clip. So the provided data is a single value only

Comment: Couldn't you much more easily illustrate the problem with a 2-vector rather than a 103-vector??